# PyGTK event definition class

Tags: pygtk

In many PyGTk tutorials, event handlers are defined like below.

```
window.connect("destroy", self.close)
button.connect("clicked", self.print_hello_world)
```

Is there any class encapsulating "destroy", "clicked" string literals as I want to access them as constants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In small apps, we may write code like this:

```
class MyApp():
    def __init__(self):
        self.win = Gtk.Window()
        self.win.set_size_request(400, 300)
        self.win.connect('destroy', self.on_app_exit)

        btn = Gtk.Button("hello")
        btn.connect('clicked', self.on_button_clicked)

    def run(self):
        self.win.show_all()
        Gtk.main()

    def on_app_exit(self, window):
        // do something.
        Gtk.main_quit()

    def on_button_clicked(self, btn):
        print('hello, world')

def main():
    app = MyApp()
    app.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```